# php post request curl HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, apache2, curl, 500-error, sms-gateway

here is my configuration : Apache2 working with php7.1.

I have an example PHP code for sending a sms message specific to JasminSMS :

```
<?php
// Sending simple message using PHP
// http://jasminsms.com

$baseurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:1401/send'

$params = '?username=foo'
$params.= '&password=bar'
$params.= '&to='.urlencode('+336222172')
$params.= '&content='.urlencode('Hello world !')

$response = file_get_contents($baseurl.$params);
?>
```

But it does not working and give me error 500.

I have two examples that works well:

```
http://127.0.0.1:1401/send?username=foo&password=bar&to=06222172&content=hello
```

and

```
curl -d "username=foo&password=bar&dlr=yes&dlr-level=3&to=xxxxxxxxxx&from=InfoMessage&dlr-url=http://exemple.com/dlr.php&content=hello !" http://127.0.0.1:1401/send
```

I need to turn them into php queries and found them next exemples :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1:1401/send");
$fp = fopen("username=foo&password=bar&dlr=yes&dlr-level=3&to=xxxxxxxxxx&from=InfoMessage&dlr-url=http://exemple.com/dlr.php&content=hello !", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>


<?php
 $ch = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1:1401/send?username=foo&password=bar&to=xxxxxxxxxx&content=hello !');
 curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

that I found here :

[Sending POST form data with php CURL](https://www.askapache.com/php/sending-post-form-data-php-curl/), [api-http-examples-php](https://www.teletopiasms.no/np/frontpage/gateway/api-http-examples-php) and I tested all these examples without result, all show me 500 error.

Maybe it needs to configure .htaccess, my file permissions are 755 with www-data.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is in your apache `error.log` ? 500 errors are internal server errors and indicate a problem with your script (typically)

Comment: I'v got these error : Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/html/yip2.php:2\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/yip2.php on line 2\n' for the second example.

Comment: You need to add `curl` support to your PHP setup.  How to do this will depend on what distro you are running...

Answer (score 2):

There is no `php-curl` installed on your machine. You should install it. Installation depends on your OS.

More details about your error could be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6382581/5625691).

Comment: Thank you, it's working after installing this: 'apt-get install php7.1-curl' , I must now make an input form from this : '<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://127.0.0.1:1401/send");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=foo&password=bar&dlr=yes&dlr-level=3&to=xxxxxxxxxxfrom=InfoMessage&dlr-url=http://example.com/dlr.php&content=hello !);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>' - Any idea ?

Comment: @hexphp111 just create form - [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) more docs.